# C# Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file that is supposed to be \n\n delimited, but of course its not.  Some of the lines contains spaces after the \n\n.  How do I find a remove all spaces after a \n\n that starts a new line but that is before any other character.

Sample:

```
\n\nData,Mo re,Data
\n\n    Some,Li st,Of
\n\n\nOther,St uff
\n\n\n\n  This is another
```

Desired Output

```
\n\nData,Mo re,Data
\n\nSome,Li st,Of
\n\nOther,St uff
\n\nThis is another
```

Regex is probably the answer, but I'm still learning regex.  Here's more or less what I've come up with `Regex.Replace(input,"^(\n{2,}\s*)", "\n\n")` but it doesn't work.

Edit: I should note that I pre-convert from various different line break encodings to `\n` before this code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash character needs escaping. Try:

```
 Regex.Replace(input,"^(\n{2,}\\s*)", "\n\n")
```

Also, you should consider changing `\\s*` to `\\s+` so you don't replace valid line starts unnecesarily.

Comment: This might be the problem. But then the OP's code wouldn't even have compiled since the escape sequence `\s` is not recognized inside a non-verbatim string, so I wonder..

Comment: I think the OP needs to retain the \\s* because of the desired output bases on the given input.  Notice that the OP also want \n\n\n replaced with \n\n.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string test = "\n\nData,Mo re,Data \r\n\n\n    Some,Li st,Of \r\n\n\n\nOther,St uff \r\n\n\n\n\n  This is another  \r\n";
        string pattern = "^\n{2,}\\s*";
        string result = Regex.Replace(test, pattern, "\n\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

First, you need the Multiline option.  Second, how does your data really look?  Notice that where you have a visible cr-lf, I put in \r\n.  I did so because you said that it is a \n\n at the beginning of a line that delimits the data.  The \n is confusing to work with, so be sure of your data.